# How to define the table structure for measured data in sqlite

Tags: database-design, performance, sqlite

I have an embedded system with an sqlite database.
How should I define the table structure for the measured data from 4 sensors?

Each sensor give us every second an numeric measured value.
The measured value should be stored with an timestamp in the database.

### Criteria are:

- Table are "fill only". There are no delete and update operations.
- `INSERT (timestamp, value)` should be fast.
- `SELECT (timestamp, value)` for an specific time range should be fast.

## First Approach: One table for all sensors

```
CREATE TABLE Measured_Values (
    id        INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    sensor_id INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    timestamp DATETIME NOT NULL,
    value     REAL,
    FOREIGN KEY (sensor_id) REFERENCES Sensor_List(id))
```

with

```
CREATE TABLE Sensor_List(
    id   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT)
```

## Second Approach: One table per sensor

```
CREATE TABLE Measured_Values_Sensor_ONE (
    id        INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    timestamp DATETIME NOT NULL,
    value     REAL)

CREATE TABLE Measured_Values_Sensor_TWO (
    id        INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    timestamp DATETIME NOT NULL,
    value     REAL)
```

and so on.

OR is there another better design?

Which design is usually used?
Which design gives me small insert time but also fast query time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second approach is not normalized: adding another sensor would require creating a new table, and querying multiple sensors would be horribly complex.

When all four sensors get a new value every second, and if you have multiple tables, then the database would have to update four tables. A single table is certainly more efficient.

For fast queries on time ranges, you need an index on the `timestamp` column.
This implies that every INSERT also needs to update the index.
(If you want fast queries on time ranges *for a single sensor*, you need another index that contains both the `sensor_id` and `timestamp` columns.)

Please note that you do not need AUTOINCREMENT when you never delete rows.
([Autoincrement In SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html))

Comment: Greate Answer @CL. My conslusion: I will take the first First Approach with one table for all sensors but remove the AUTOINCREMENT. As well I define an index `CREATE INDEX sensor_Time_Index ON Measured_Values (sensor_id , timestamp);`